# Maintain Original Formatting with Hyperlinks

Tags: css, hyperlink, html-heading

I am trying to set up links within a webpage to parts of the same page, but want to maintain the original text formatting, which was a simple h4 heading. I have tried many things, including putting the h4 setting and text-decoration set to none in a style, but while the underline from the link is removed, it will not revert back to the color and size of the h4 heading. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code looks like, but a structure like this would prevent the `h4` styles from becoming messed up ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTdyt/)):

HTML:

```
<a href="#contact" class="self_page">
    <h4>Contact Us</h4>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
h4 {
    color:#666333;
    font-family:Georgia,serif;
}
a.self_page {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the markup is

```
<h4><a href="...">Some heading</a></h4>
```

(which uses the valid way of nesting `h4` and `a` elements), and if the color of `h4`elements is black (the default), the following style sheet removes link formatting, making the heading text look just the same as if the `a` markup were not there:

```
h4 a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

If the color of `h4` elements is not black, modify the style sheet rule that sets its color so that the selector `h4 a` is added. E.g., if it is `h4 { color: orange }`, change it to `h4, h4 a { color: orange }`. (You could make the link inherit its parent’s color, using `h4 a { color: inherit }`, but the `inherit` value is not supported by all browsers.)

If you want to hide the link even on mouseover, when the pointer (erroneously called “cursor” in CSS terminology) by default changes to a hand, you can add this:

```
h4 a {
   cursor: text;
}
```